# Is there a marlin setting to disable XY axes when Z endstop triggered?

Tags: marlin, safety, endstop

I have a mechanical switch connected to a RAMPS 1.4 board that detects when my laser has run in to something.  Right now, I have it set as a Z limit, so if I move too far in the Z and crash the laser in to something, it stops but I can still back away.  That works great, but is there a simple configuration change in marlin so that it also disables the X and Y movement?  This switch can detect impact to the laser from any direction, so I'd like to protect against X or Y movements snapping the laser off sideways.

The desired behavior is:  if the switch is closed, everything acts normally, but if the switch is open, its only possible to move in the -z direction (which moves the stage down away from the laser).

If this is not a configuration change, does anyone have a hint on where in the marlin code to start making changes?